# MSBuild.exe not building projects in parallel

Tags: c++, windows, msbuild, build-process

I use MSBuild.exe to build my Visual C++ Solution.  One project in the solution compiles to a static library (let's called it MyLib.lib), and the many other projects are small tools which link to MyLib.lib.

I compile it like this:
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Win32" /maxcpucount:4

However I can see that each project is build sequentially.  There is always only one MSBuild.exe running.

Am I doing anything wrong?

[edit: I'm using Visual Studio 2008]

Comment: What do you expect to be done in parallel if one project depends on the other?

Comment: Sorry - I edited the question to make this clearer.  In my solution, there are about 15 projects which depend on the MyLib.lib.  I would expect these 15 projects to be built in parallel once MyLib.lib has been built on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only projects that don't depend on each other can be built in parallel.  Clearly that's not your case, can't build the tool until the .lib is available.

EDIT: you are not using VS2010.  For VS2008 you should use vcbuild.exe.  Enable concurrent builds with /M4

Comment: So I would need one solution which builds MyLib.lib, and another solution with my other projects which depend on it?

Comment: The projects from the second solution would have no dependancy (they just link the a .lib file which already exists and was built from the first solution) so they should be able to be built in parallel

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work on my machine.  I will modify our build script!  I used these arguments with vcbuild:
vcbuild.exe" /rebuild /M4 MySolution.sln "Release|Win32"

Answer (score -1):

Projects have to be compiled one-by-one, since there are dependencies.
Anyway MSBuild is not performing the compilation in parallel.